# Take non zero values, and adjacent data, from one sheet and create new table in another sheet - VBA loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take the output from a solver model and condense it into a summary report in another sheet. The Solver screen will be lost each time I run it on new data.

My solver screen looks like this
[Solver screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFzvq.png). The ideal report output will be [this table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P18md.png) Notice that January only has two truckloads (TLs) as Solver output (IF(E4:N4=True,Include TL,n/a). So, the new report should skip TLs #3,4,5 (G4:I4) and fill in the table with next valid output (column J). I will always want to associate the unit quantity (E:N) with a product name (D) in the new report.

I am a super novice VBA user. Here is how far I have got in my VBA to accomplish this:

```
Sub TL_Report()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("e5:e30")
If c.Value <> 0 Then
Worksheets("TL_Report").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2).Value = Range(c.Offset(0, -1), c).Value
End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I can figure out how to loop through each column in the solver, but I cannot figure out how to have the new report get reformatted without blanks entries. Any advice on how to write this? Thank you.

Comment: Your report has 10 rows for each truck-month. Do you need the top-ten list for each truck-month? Do you want a full list? Does each truck-month be at the same rows' distance from one to another?

Comment: What's the purpouse of the "Delivery" cell in each truck-month in the report?

Comment: In your report the 3rd chapter is marked as truck 3 february (i assume), still it refers to truck 1 february. Is that 3 supposed to indicate the truck number or does it refers to the chapter number of the report?

Comment: Hello @EvilBlueMonkey, thank you for so much help. 

1. My report needs to accommodate a row for up to 20 unique products in each truckload.

2. The "Delivery" month in the report will reflect which month that TL was found in the solver (Row 4 in Solver)

3. It refers to the chapter # in the report. The TL# in Solver is only used on that tab. The sequence of trucks #s in the report should always be a continuous series. i.e. The first truck delivered is #1, whether it is in Jan, Feb, Mar.

BTW, the Report tab is named "TL_Report" and the solver resides on "TL_Solver"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the data avaiable, i've created this subroutine:

```
Sub SubReport()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksSource As Worksheet
    Dim WksReport As Worksheet
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet
    Dim RngMonths As Range
    Dim RngTrucks As Range
    Dim RngProductList As Range
    Dim RngValues As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim DblCounter01 As Integer
    Dim DblCounter02 As Integer
    
    'Setting WksSource.
    Set WksSource = Sheets("TL_Solver")
    
    'Referring to WksSource.
    With WksSource
        
        'Setting RngMonths.
        Set RngRange01 = .Range("E2")
        DblCounter01 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(RngRange01.End(xlToRight).Column, _
                                                   .Cells(RngRange01.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column _
                                                  )
        Set RngMonths = .Range( _
                               RngRange01, _
                               .Cells(RngRange01.Row, DblCounter01) _
                              )
        
        'Setting RngTrucks.
        Set RngRange01 = .Range("E3")
        DblCounter01 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(RngRange01.End(xlToRight).Column, _
                                                   .Cells(RngRange01.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column _
                                                  )
        Set RngTrucks = .Range( _
                               RngRange01, _
                               .Cells(RngRange01.Row, DblCounter01) _
                              )
        
        'Setting RngProductList.
        Set RngRange01 = RngTrucks.Resize(1, 1).Offset(2, -1)
        DblCounter01 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(RngRange01.End(xlDown).Row, _
                                                   .Cells(.Rows.Count, RngRange01.Column).End(xlUp).Row _
                                                  )
        Set RngProductList = .Range( _
                             RngRange01, _
                             .Cells(DblCounter01, RngRange01.Column) _
                            )
        
        'Setting RngValues.
        Set RngRange01 = .Cells(RngProductList.Row, RngTrucks.Column)
        Set RngValues = RngRange01.Resize(RngProductList.Rows.Count, RngTrucks.Columns.Count)
        
    End With
    
    'Creating a new worksheet for the report.
    Set WksReport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=WksSource)
    
    'Counting other existing reports if any.
    DblCounter01 = 0
    For Each WksWorksheet01 In WksReport.Parent.Worksheets()
        If Left(WksWorksheet01.Name, 7) = "Report " Then
            DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    'Renaming the current report.
    DblCounter02 = DblCounter01
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until WksReport.Name = "Report " & DblCounter01
        DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
        WksReport.Name = "Report " & DblCounter01
        If DblCounter01 - DblCounter02 > 1000 Then GoTo CP_FAILED_RENAMING
    Loop
CP_FAILED_RENAMING:
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Setting RngTarget.
    Set RngTarget = WksReport.Range("A1")
    
    'Covering each column in RngValues.
    For DblCounter01 = 1 To RngValues.Columns.Count
        
        'Checking if there is any value to report.
        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RngValues.Columns(DblCounter01).Cells) <> 0 Then
        
            'Inserting the data for the first row of the report's chapter.
            With RngTarget
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Truck #"
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = Split(RngTrucks.Cells(1, DblCounter01), "#")(1)
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = "Delivery"
                If WksSource.Cells(RngMonths.Row, RngTrucks.Columns(DblCounter01).Column).Value = "" Then
                    .Offset(0, 4).Value = WksSource.Cells(RngMonths.Row, RngTrucks.Columns(DblCounter01).Column).End(xlToLeft).Value
                Else
                    .Offset(0, 4).Value = WksSource.Cells(RngMonths.Row, RngTrucks.Columns(DblCounter01).Column).Value
                End If
                .Offset(1, 1).Value = "Product"
                .Offset(1, 2).Value = "Quantity"
            End With
            
            'Offsetting RngTarget by 2 rows in order to enter the data.
            Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(2, 0)
            
            'Covering each value in the given column of RngValues.
            DblCounter02 = 1
            For Each RngRange01 In RngValues.Columns(DblCounter01).Cells
                'Checking if the value is not 0.
                If RngRange01.Value <> 0 Then
                    'Inserting the data.
                    With RngTarget
                        .Value = DblCounter02
                        .Offset(0, 1).Value = WksSource.Cells(RngRange01.Row, RngProductList.Column).Value
                        .Offset(0, 2).Value = RngRange01.Value
                    End With
                    DblCounter02 = DblCounter02 + 1
                    'Offsetting RngTarget to the next row of the report.
                    Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next
            
            'Offsetting RngTarget by 1 row for the next chapter.
            Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
            
        End If
    Next
    
    'Autofitting the second column of the report.
    RngTarget.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
End Sub
```

It dynamically determines the size of the data to process (starting from given cells), it creates a new sheet renamed as "Report *n*" (based of the *n* pre-existing sheet already named "Report *n*") and insert the data as requested.

Comment: This sub does work. Only minor formatting issues to be resolved, and these exist due to my poor problem definition. Very cool sub, I really appreciate it!

Comment: So is it fine? Do you need any extra help?

Comment: Yes, this was extremely helpful!!